# Why is the background-color not working for the "progress" element with an ":indeterminate" pseudo-class?

Tags: html

I know that you can change the background of a "progress" element using a -webkit-, however, in the developers.mozilla.org (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate) it says that, you can add ":indeterminate" pseudo-class, and then if the "progress" element doesn't have a value, you should be able to change its background-color, but it's not working for me. Are they wrong?

```css
.banana progress:indeterminate {
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="banana">
  <form>

    <progress>

        </form>
    </div>
```

The box-shadow works, but the background-color does not.

Once again, i can change the background-color of progress, without having the pseudo-class, using a -webkit-, but why is it not working with a pseudo-class and with just typing "blackground-color:", the way developers.mozilla.org said it should work. Are they wrong for saying that, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome

Comment: which version of browser are you using because that pseudo class doesn't support early browsers

Comment: Really? I am using Chrome too, and it's not working for me.

Comment: @Gad Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: check this link you can find better [progress](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

Comment: I'm on the same version of Chrome as you, and it is working for me as well.  Is it possible that the effect is too subtle to see given your monitor and viewing settings?  Have you tried making it a very bold bright or dark color to verify that this isn't an optical issue?

Comment: @AlexanderNied No, that's definitely not an issue. I've made it red, and zoomed it on the browser 200% to see it closely. It's definitely not changing color. I think the most likely scenario is that there is some interference by some other code. I've been using the same page to practice all these dozens of elements. Although i don't see how there can be any interference, that's the only explanation i can think of. But at least the fact that it works for you guys means that the code itself is working.